# Getting value from array - Python

Tags: python, numpy

My apologies in advance for the stupid question you are going to read.

I have: data =(14, 168000),  value = 1.

What does the `[0]` in `data = np.where (data == _value) [0]` do?

Do I get the first row in the data array?

Comment: _Do I get the first row in the data array?_ Did you try it to see what you get?

Comment: okai the difference I get when printing data with and without '[0]' is that the shape changes from (21000, ) with [0] to (1, 21000) without [0]. Why?

Comment: Look at `np.where(data==_value)`.  That is a 2 element tuple (see the docs for `np.nonzero`).  The `[0]` selects the first array from that tuple, the `row` indices.